# RTSP Server Gstreamer

Tags: server, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp, gstreamer-1.0

I have to build a test server (C++ application) to familiarize with the RTSP implementation of the GStreamer library.

My task is to make something like this:
MP4 video file ==> RTSP application ==> Network stream ==> VLC Client which reproduces the video.

I think it's one of the simplest things for this library, it's like an "Hello World" of RTSP, however, i cannot find an example of this.

How may i accomplish this? Where may i find a quick step-by-step explanation of the GStreamer operation?

Cheers

Comment: https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/tree/master/examples

Comment: Thanks Florian, what example should i choose in your opinion?

Comment: I think you can start from the test launch file. https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-launch.c